# node-webkit window menu not showing up

Tags: node-webkit

I have the following file in node-webkit but no window menu is showing up. I do get the alert I have in there so it's running the code. I'm using win 7. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using node.js <script>document.write(process.version)</script>.

    <script>
    var nw = require('nw.gui');

    var windowMenu = new nw.Menu({ 
        type: 'menubar' 
    });

    nw.Window.get().menu = windowMenu;

    var helpMenu = new nw.Menu();
    windowMenu.append(new nw.MenuItem({
        label: 'Help',
        submenu: helpMenu
    }));

    alert("test 2");
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time you add the menu to the current window (nw.Window.get().menu = windowMenu;)  ...   the menu is empty (blank).  Move this line below the code which adds a menuitem -- for example, place this line at the point where your current code has the "alert" -- and the menu will be non-empty (and visible).

Comment: Ah the order! That makes sense. I'll have to go back to the youtube video I was watching to get this because I had this exactly like he did.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecc0JopiZe4 He doesn't do what you say and it works for him, but not me. Strange.

Comment: As you noted, the youtube video from last year shows your original code.  On my Windows 7 system, the youtube code does NOT work, even for old releases of NW.  The documentation points out that menubar implementation on MACs have a number of differences -- I suspect that you have uncovered an undocumented OS-dependent difference. (The youtube coder is on a MAC, I believe).